pdfjs-dist Integration Problem in Quasar Framework with Vue 3
After run the development mode from command quasar dev, I get the following error:
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry" from "src\pages\PdfViewer.vue". Does the file exist?

D:/project/project-frontend/src/pages/PdfViewer.vue:7:28

1  |  
2  |  import { pdfjsLib } from "pdfjs-dist";
3  |  import pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";
   |                             ^
4  |  
5  |  pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;


It seems for some reason it does not resolve imports and in side node modules I got this structure,

Could you let me know how to resolve this? Thanks in advance
installed the package by npm install pdfjs-dist and implemented my custom component,which is
PdfViewer.vue,
<template>
  <div ref="pdfViewerContainer" class="pdf-viewer"></div>
</template>

<script>
import { pdfjsLib } from "pdfjs-dist";
import pdfjsWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry";

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;

export default {
  props: {
    pdfUrl: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    searchText: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pdf: null,
      currentPage: 1,
      totalPage: 0,
    };
  },
  watch: {
    searchText() {
      this.highlightText();
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loadPdf();
  },
  methods: {
    async loadPdf() {
      const loadingTask = pdfjsLib.getDocument(this.pdfUrl);
      const pdf = await loadingTask.promise;
      this.pdf = pdf;
      this.totalPage = pdf.numPages;
      this.renderPage(this.currentPage);
    },
    async renderPage(pageNumber) {
      const page = await this.pdf.getPage(pageNumber);
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;
      const renderContext = {
        canvasContext: context,
        viewport: viewport,
      };
      await page.render(renderContext).promise;

      const textContent = await page.getTextContent();
      const div = document.createElement("div");
      div.setAttribute("class", "textLayer");
      pdfjsLib.renderTextLayer({
        textContent,
        container: div,
        viewport,
        textDivs: [],
      });

      this.$refs.pdfViewerContainer.innerHTML = "";
      this.$refs.pdfViewerContainer.appendChild(canvas);
      this.$refs.pdfViewerContainer.appendChild(div);

      this.highlightText();
    },
    highlightText() {
      const textLayer =
        this.$refs.pdfViewerContainer.querySelector(".textLayer");
      if (!textLayer) return;

      const textDivs = textLayer.childNodes;
      textDivs.forEach((div) => {
        if (div.textContent.includes(this.searchText)) {
          div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        }
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.pdf-viewer {
  position: relative;
}
.textLayer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
</style>



According to the error msg, guessing you need to use a plugin 'vite-plugin-pdfjs', and this plugin seems not to be updated for a very long time...

@huanfeng correct seems it doesn't support vue3 yet.

You can try to import the pdf.worker.js:
Reference code from: https://github.com/upthen/use-pdfjs-in-vue3
<template>
  <div class="pdf-container">
    <canvas id="pdf-canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import * as PDFJS from "pdfjs-dist";
import * as PdfWorker from "pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js";
import { nextTick, onMounted, ref } from "vue";
import PdfBook from "@/assets/JavaScript.pdf";

window.pdfjsWorker = PdfWorker;
let pdfDoc: any = null;
const pdfPages = ref(0);
const pdfScale = ref(1.5);
const pdfContainerRef = ref<HTMLElement | null>(null);

const loadFile = (url: any) => {
  // 设定pdfjs的 workerSrc 参数
  PDFJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = PdfWorker;
  const loadingTask = PDFJS.getDocument(url);
  loadingTask.promise
    .then(async (pdf: any) => {
      pdf.loadingParams.disableAutoFetch = true;
      pdf.loadingParams.disableStream = true;
      pdfDoc = pdf; // 保存加载的pdf文件流
      pdfPages.value = pdfDoc.numPages; // 获取pdf文件的总页数
      await nextTick(() => {
        renderPage(1); // 将pdf文件内容渲染到canvas
      });
    })
    .catch((error: any) => {
      console.warn(`[upthen] pdfReader loadFile error: ${error}`);
    });
};

const renderPage = (num: any) => {
  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then((page: any) => {
    page.cleanup();
    const canvas: any = document.getElementById(`pdf-canvas`);
    if (canvas) {
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      const dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
      const bsr =
        ctx.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
        ctx.backingStorePixelRatio ||
        1;
      const ratio = dpr / bsr;
      const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: pdfScale.value });
      canvas.width = viewport.width * ratio;
      canvas.height = viewport.height * ratio;
      canvas.style.width = viewport.width + "px";
      canvas.style.height = viewport.height + "px";
      ctx.setTransform(ratio, 0, 0, ratio, 0, 0);
      const renderContext = {
        canvasContext: ctx,
        viewport: viewport,
      };
      page.render(renderContext);
    }
  });
};

onMounted(() => {
  loadFile(PdfBook);
});
</script>


Tried it but didn't helpful for my scenario, appreciate the support, I did resolve it by using a backend library instead of frontend

It's ok, glad to hear you have solved the issue.
